# Working with PSD on psd.js library

Tags: javascript, image, photoshop, psd

I have a requirement from a client to show images from a PSD(photoshop) file which have multiple layers, on each layer there will be an image, I did some research about it but haven't got any leads, so far I come up with a JS library named psd.js, but I think that is only for parsing and converting to image format(not sure haven't found much documentation on internet). please suggest me if there is any open source library for reading and editing PSD files. (javascript or asp.net preferred)

here is my snippet I have tried so far but haven't got any success, please let me know if there is any way to work with PSDs

thanks.

```
PSD.fromURL("images/example.psd")
.then(function(psd) {
    psd.tree()._children[3]._children[0].visble = false;
   document.getElementById('ImageContainer')
           .appendChild(psd.image.toPng());
   console.log(psd.tree().export());
});
```

Comment: What error does itshow?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for a project of mine, for that you can use imagemagick they even have a [command line tool](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) that can make the process very easy. It will let you extract the images from each layer. You can also use psd.js to get information about the each layer positioning and other information.

Hope this helps.